# Bem naming underscore, hyphen or camelcase in element names

Tags: css, naming-conventions, bem

I have an element call "user nav"

Currently I have

```
.header__user-nav
```

With a modifier

```
.header__user-nav--active
```

Is it better to use single underscores for element names

```
  .header__user_nav--active
```

or hyphens

```
  .header__user-nav--active
```

or camelcase

```
  .header__userNav--active
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it is just a matter of taste. See https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#alternative-naming-schemes

Comment: Great, well I will go with .header__user-nav--active